# Convoluted Conditional List comprehension

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a set of tuples, each consist of 4 integers (A, B, C, D)

And I have a input tuple (x, y, z, w) of 4 integer

I wanted to make a list of all element in the set where

```
(abs(A - x) + abs(B - y) + abs(C - z) + abs(D - w)) / 4 <= i
```

Where i is a user-defined threshold.

I'm trying a method obtained by another guy from another question, that is to do a List comprehension, I tried the following:

```
SET = my set of 4-tuples
input = the input tuple

for w in [element for element in SET
                              if ((sum(abs(x - y)) for x, y in zip(element, input)) / 4) <= i]:

      Do something here
```

but I keep getting error messages like:

```
if ((sum(abs(x - y)) for x, y in zip(key, js)) / 4) == 0]:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'generator' and 'int'
```

I have no idea how to solve that problem, I looked up the definition of a generator it said a generator is just a function that behaves like a iterator, I assume it is my *sum(abs(x - y))*, but this thing should return a number, I'm so confused, please help me out, thank you very much!!!

Comment: Just to clarify, is `(A, B, C, D)` a set of tuples or a tuple of integers? My take from what you are trying to accomplish is that it is a tuple of integers like so `(1, 2, 3, 4)`. It would help if you provided examples as to what your inputs look like. Also, a snippet of the relevant code, preferably a minimal working example, would be useful as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to divide a `generator` by an `int`.

```
for w in [element for element in SET
    if ((sum(abs(x - y)) for x, y in zip(element, input)) / 4) <= i]:
        ^---------------- right here -------------------^
```

is your generator.

You need the `sum` to run over the whole of the generator, and divide that result by 4.

```
    if (sum((abs(x - y)) for x, y in zip(element, input)) / 4) <= i]:
```

Note that sum is out one paren.  Of course, that doesn't work, since `zip(element, input)` isn't valid (`element` isn't iterable).  I'm not sure what it's supposed to be.  If it's `element` matched with each value of `input`, use `(element, )*4`.

Edit:  I just reread your question, if I understand, `SET` is something like `{(1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8)}`, at which point it is iterable, and should work if you fix the generator issue.